# How can I make this function not generate a "doesn't return a value on all paths" warning?

Tags: vb.net

I realize this is a very specific question, and not very helpful outside of this scenario, although I am sure it applies to other questions with the same problem. I have a function to recursively search through windows (and their child windows) to find specific ones, it works exactly as expected, however it causes "function doesn't return a value on all paths" warning. This is the only warning in my entire program, and although it might be silly, I'm interested in knowing if there is a way to stop this error from occurring, but still allowing the function to work properly.

```
    Public Function FindQWidgetWindows() As Integer
    Dim hWndStart As Integer = 0
    Dim WindowText As String = "*"
    Dim Classname As String = "QWidget"
    Dim hwnd As Integer
    Dim sWindowText As String
    Dim sClassname As String
    Dim r As Integer
    Static level As Integer

    If level = 0 Then
        If hWndStart = 0 Then hWndStart = GetDesktopWindow()
    End If

    level = level + 1

    hwnd = GetWindow(hWndStart, GW_CHILD)

    Do Until hwnd = 0
        Call FindQWidgetWindows()

        'Get the window text and class name'
        sWindowText = Space$(255)
        r = GetWindowText(hwnd, sWindowText, 255)
        sWindowText = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(sWindowText, r)
        sClassname = Space$(255)
        r = GetClassName(hwnd, sClassname, 255)
        sClassname = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(sClassname, r)

        If (sWindowText Like WindowText) And (sClassname Like Classname) Then
            Dim aRECT As RECT
            Dim hwndInt As Int32 = hwnd
            GetWindowRect(hwndInt, aRECT)
            FindQWidgetWindows = hwnd

            'uncommenting the next line causes the routine to'
            'only return the first matching window.'
            'Exit Do'

        End If

        hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)

    Loop

    level = level - 1
End Function
```

Comment: Let me respond to your comments, and clarify. First, thanks for your answers. However, I understand WHY it's giving the warning, I just haven't been able to fix the warning.
@paxdiablo - yes, but if I make it a sub, it won't work - in fact it'll return an error on the line "FindQWidgetWindows = hwnd"
@Shoban that's sort of the behavior I wanted, if it finds a window it returns the value, if it doesn't it shouldn't return anything (or rather I suppose, I should be returning Nothing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rely on the fact, that VB automatically declares a return variable with the name of your function. This variable can be used as any other variable in your function. So it also can get a default initialization.

As already mentioned, you only assign a value in a very nested `If` statement.
You should simply initialize your variable outside and before of your `Do`-loop with something like

```
FindQWidgetWindows = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to fix the return in the (very) nested If's, but assigning the Nothing value prior to the loop fixed the warning. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get rid of this error by ensuring every path returns a value.

This can be done by simply initialising the return value at the top of the function:

```
FindQWidgetWindows = Nothing
```

But you have another problem that you're probably not seeing because your desired window is at the top level. If you recurse into your function, the `hWndStart` will once again be set to the desktop, not the child window.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's a Function, and it IS returning the parent window to work correctly recursively.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the below code will be executed only if the `If` condition is satisfied.

```
FindQWidgetWindows = hwnd
```

Which also means if the If condition is not satisfied nothing will be returned.

Comment: I orginally tried changing that to
    FindQWidgetWindows = hwnd
    Else
    FindQWidgetWindows = Nothing
but that didn't solve the warning. - and apparently I'm not smart enough to use code tags in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the function (`Public Function FindQWidgetWindows() As Integer`) as returning a integer but the function doesn't return anything. Just ensure that you return an integer using the `Return` statement.