# VB.NET function return value

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB.NET Function Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451025/vb-net-function-return)

If I have a function that returns a boolean, what is the difference between:

```
Return False
```

and

```
Function = False
```

Comment: Please read this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451025/vb-net-function-return

Comment: Thanks that was very informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Return False` immediately exits the function so nothing further is executed.

Setting `FunctionName = False` allows the return value to be assigned again before the function exits.

Personally I'd stick with `Return` as it's much clearer what you're trying to do. Assigning to the function name is left over from VB6.

Comment: Thanks. So with `Return False` will the caller "see" the value "False"? In other words if I say `If Function() = False Then do something` will that work if I just `Return False` or do I have to set `Function = False`?

Comment: @JJD Yes, both ways will work like that.

Answer (score 0):

the Return statement also exits the function. Assigning a value to the function name does not. Your function will keep executing until the end, so you could potentially change that value again.