# VB.NET Execution Order

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, return

I am currently working on converting some VB source code over to C#.  While I understand there are converters to automate this, and that I could actually use this particular dll without rewriting it, I'm doing it partially so I can understand VB better.  Not so much as to expect to write it, but it's at least helping me to be able to read it.

In doing this though, I've come across something that is quite confusing. The following code snippets are examples, but I've seen it throughout the program.

**VB Source Code:**

```
Friend Function AllocateObjectNumber() As Long
    AllocateObjectNumber = _nextFreeObjectNumber
    _nextFreeObjectNumber += 1
    _objectAllocatedCount += 1
End Function
```

**My translated C# Code:**

```
    internal long AllocateObjectNumber()
    {
        cvNextFreeObjectNumber += 1;
        cvObjectAllocatedCount += 1;
        return cvNextFreeObjectNumber;
    }
```

What I'm not understanding is the flow control that VB uses.  I understand that `AllocateObjectNumber += 1` is used in place of `return cvNextFreeObjectNumber`, but if this line comes before the incrementing of the two variables, then how is that code not considered unreachable?  Based on my C# understanding, the first line in this method would immediately return to the calling method, and this whole method would basically act as a pseudo-Property.

Any helpful explanations?

Comment: It happened, because the variable and return function is a long type, and therefore a value type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VB approach is more similar to storing the value in a temporary variable:

```
internal long AllocateObjectNumber()
{
    var nextNumber = _nextFreeObjectNumber
    cvNextFreeObjectNumber += 1;
    cvObjectAllocatedCount += 1;
    return nextNumber;
}
```

In VB the `function = value` syntax doesn't do a `return` - so the code after can keep running. When that method reaches the end, then the value you used becomes the 'return' value for whatever called it in the first place.

You can use the `function = value` syntax multiple times in the same method as a way of returning a different result in different conditions without needing the temporary variable I used in my example.

Comment: Nice answer. VB's "set the return value of this function to some value" vs C#s "return with this value" can be confusing to begin with.

Comment: While correct, that VB code style is a holdout from the old VB6 days.  It is confusing to most and shouldn't be used.  Standard "Return" syntax as used in C# should be used these days.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely explains how it could be useful to have this feature as well.  One downside to translating this has been that while I'm seeing **how** to do things in VB, it doesn't necessarily explain **why** to do it that way.

Comment: Question about the different return types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451025/vb-net-function-return.  I agree with sentiment here, the return statement is modern practice. Setting the function name to a value is confusing, it requires extra thought cycle to realize it's the function return value and not some class property.

Answer (score 4):

> Based on my C# understanding, the first line in this method would immediately return to the calling method

But it’s not C# code, it’s VB code. `AllocateObjectNumber = _nextFreeObjectNumber` does *not* return, it just assigns a return value. The actual return is at the end of the method.

Most people would actually write the VB code identical to the C# code, i.e. using `Return` explicitly. The assign-to-method-name style is a remnant of older VB versions where it was the *only* way of returning a value from a function. In VB.NET, you can use both.

Comment: nice explanation - it looks to me as though the VB.NET code was poorly upgraded VB6 code

Comment: @Matt I wouldn’t say that there’s anything wrong with the code. You can certainly use a separate variable to store the return value – I probably would – but that’s arguably unnecessary. It’s more a question of style.

Comment: One thing I'm discovering in doing this is the tendency of VB to have multiple ways to do the same thing, as opposed to C# having basically 1 (sometimes 2) ways to do it.  It's definitely providing a challenge.  :)

Comment: @KevenM Yeah, that’s essentially due to VB’s legacy, whereas C# was designed from the ground up.

Comment: @KevenM - Thats only because VB.NET supports VB6 syntax or it did back in .NET 1.0 :-)

Comment: @Ramhound It never did. It *attempts* to be as backwards compatible as possible to ease migration, but nothing more. VB.NET 1.0 code is still valid modern VB, they did not reduce the syntax in the meantime.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Its been over a decade and a half since I learned VB.NET and I was using the pre-beta version of both Visual Studio .NET and .NET Framework but I specificatly remember being able to declare functions using the new and old VB 6 synatx. I was just pointing out the "multiple" are caused by this limited syntax support.  Why a college course was offered on a beta product I will never understand but it was the most stable beta product I have ever tested.

Comment: @Ramhound What’s the old syntax of function declaration? FWIW I also used the pre-beta version, *and* VB6. I don’t remember a different syntax.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I will again point out its been 13 years since I learned VB.NEt and 12 and half years since I actually used it.  I will be honest I don't remember everything exactly I just recall being told the "new" way and the "old" way and I had to remember to enable something very specific to allow the old syntax.