# Declare a VB.net method which will return list of integers

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I got an assignment to change some things on vb.net project. Since I'm working with C# most of the time, I'm having some issues with some things.

What I want to know is how can I create a method which will return list of integers, something in C# like `private List<int> NameOfMethod()`.

So I'm trying something like:

```
Private Sub GetSourcesInfo() As
```

And this method will need to return list of integers, how can I achieve that in VB.net?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451025/vb-net-function-return shows 2 ways to return value along with showing syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB, you specify generic parameters using the keyword `Of`

```
Private Function GetSourcesInfo() As List(Of Integer)
```

This can lead to parenthesis chaining statements that look kind of funny to someone coming from C#, like

```
Dim someList As New List(Of Integer)()  ' Calls the constructor
```

Answer (score 4):

That would be a Function:

```
Private Function GetSourcesInfo() As List(Of Integer)
 ' code that builds a List(Of Integer)
End Function
```