# Performance Implications of Dimming Locally vs Assigning to Function Name (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

Can't show the actual code because proprietary software, but essentially something like this

```
Public FunctionA(ByVal paramOne As Int32) As Int32
    FunctionA = SomeCalculation()
    If FunctionA < paramOne Then Return FunctionA
    Return 0
End Function
```

versus

```
Public FunctionA(ByVal paramOne As Int32) As Int32
    Dim temp As Int32 = SomeCalculation()
    If temp < paramOne Then Return temp
    Return 0 
End Function
```

This is a really simplified example, but I was wondering what VB.NET would be doing under the hood and therefore which is generally considered better coding practice

Comment: Hello!  Did you see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3056584/3791245) about this topic?  And personally I never like how that syntax in VB reads anyway (set return value by using Function name).  Seems that syntax was mostly left for easy porting of VB6 code, not for general use.

Comment: The syntax for returning a value in the name of the function goes back to at least qbasic.

Comment: The first block is something I would immediately refactor.  It's mixing the use of `Return` to return a value and setting the implicit result variable; I would expect one or the other (consistently) but not both.  As far as performance goes, in most cases, I would expect an optimized build to compile down to the same machine instructions, and even if it doesn't, it would normally have a negligible impact on performance.

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't worry about performance at this granularity until you have profiling data to indicate that it's a real problem.  Even highly-skilled humans are generally terrible at guessing performance based on low-level construction (see some of Eric Lippert's recent blogs, he's an expert in C# *who worked on the compiler* and he still is frequently wrong in guesses about performance---it's also instructive because the huge gains are all driven by algorithmic and data structure changes, which is usually where the big performance wins are found).

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the wrong question. That first code snippet is not something you should ever be using at all. The whole point of using the implicitly-named variable is that it gets returned by default. The "proper" way to use it is like this:

```vb
Public FunctionA(ByVal paramOne As Int32) As Int32
    FunctionA = SomeCalculation()
    If FunctionA >= paramOne Then Return 0
End Function
```

As you can see, if nothing is explicitly returned, the value of that variable is implicitly returned.

The issue is here is not what happens under the hood. It's what happens right before your eyes. VB does not require that you use parentheses when calling a method so, if a method has no parameters, you can call it simply using its name. That means that, inside the method, using that implicitly-named local variable looks exactly like a call to the method anywhere else. That's inconsistent and error-prone, therefore it's bad.

Making your code readable should be your first concern and you should only sacrifice that readability for genuine gains in other areas. There is no gain to using that implicitly-named variable so don't use it. Declare all your variables and always use explicit `Return` statements.

Comment: Looks like a field not a function.